# How to use a href while using htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

Let's say if I have this code

```
$text = "please visit this <a href="http://example.com">site</a>."
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
echo $text;
```

so it's output will be `please visit this <a href="http://example.com">site</a>.`
but I want it's output like this 
please visit this [site](http://example.com). 
is there is a way to see if it's a href then do somthing?
Thanks.

Comment: put the function into the variable value, if you don't like all the string to be passed to it. Also escape the quotes

Comment: Change your quotes on your string.  Wrap the entire string in single quotes.  Should be 'please visit this <a href="http://example.com">site</a>.'.  Or escape your quotes like Royal said.

Comment: Don't escape the data. Use a DOM based XSS file that whitelists acceptable elements and attributes.

Comment: If you want to allow your users to enter only certain HTML, consider using an existing HTML sanitizer library such as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Comment: For one thing, you're missing your `;` at the end of `$text = "please visit this <a href="http://example.com">site</a>."`. **Tell me that's TYPO.**

Answer (score 3):

Only escape the URL itself:

```
$text = 'please visit this <a href="' . htmlspecialchars('http://example.com') . '">site</a>.'
```

Notice the switching between single and double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Your string definition is bad (as you can see by the syntax highlighting).
You don't actually need to escape anything in this instance since you want functional HTML.

You can use escape characters like so:

```
$text = "please visit this <a href=\"http://example.com\">site</a>."
                                   ^- escape here      ^- and here
```

Sometimes you can get away with using a different set of quotes, like:

```
// use single quote
$text = 'please visit this <a href="http://example.com">site</a>.'
```

Another possibility is HEREDOC notation: (stackoverflow doesn't recognize the syntax)

```
$text = <<<DELIM
please visit this <a href="http://example.com">site</a>.
DELIM;
```

Comment: While that is good advice, it doesn't answer the question (which is about escaping (HTML) special characters while still allowing the input to contain HTML links).